# Color SURF detector

Tags: opencv, surf

[SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) by default works on Gray image. I am thinking to do SURF on HSV image. My method is to separate the channels into H, S and V. And I use S and V for  keypoint detection. I tried to compare the number of keypoints in SV vs RGB and in terms of channel wise, HSV gives more features.

[image]

Not sure what I am doing is correct or not. Need some explanation of the possibility of applying SURF on HSV image. I have read a paper on applying SIFT on different color space but not SURF.

1. Is there better way to achieve this?
2. Can we apply SURF to color, HSV space?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think it's possible to extract SURF on HSV image. But bear in mind that the value ranges of S and V channels are different (and are also different from the gray scale image), so you need to carefully tune the hessianThreshold parameter to make the result reasonable. And it is also important to figure out how to consolidate the keypoints from different channels.

Comment: In openCV the range of HSV is different to the standard HSV. In OpenCV the H is between 0-180 while both S and V is between 0 - 255. I think that grayscale is between 0-255 as well that is 8bit. So I guess what i have attempted above look ok. How you feel about it?

Comment: The results look reasonable. Here is an paper that you may be interested in: [Color-SURF: A surf descriptor with local kernel color histograms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5360809). But looks like they still use gray scale for the keypoints detection and compute Color-SURF descriptors.

Answer (score 7):

> 2. Can we apply SURF to color, HSV space?

I didn't test it, but as far as I know, SIFT and SURF use quite (in principle) similar detection techniques:

SIFT detector uses the [Difference-of-Gaussian (DoG)](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-dog.html) technique to efficiently approximate the [Laplacian-of-Gaussian (LoG)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm), which both are   [Blob Detection](http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) techniques.

SURF detector uses *box-filters/box-blurs* of arbitrary size to compute (or approximate?) *The determinant of the Hessian* which is a *Blob Detection* technique.

Both methods use some strategy to compute those blobs in multiple scales (SIFT: DoG-Pyramid; SURF: integral images to scale the filter sizes). At the end, both methods detect *blobs* in the given 2D array.

So if SIFT can detect good features in your (H)SV channels, SURF should be able to do the same because in principle they both detect blobs. What you will do is detecting blobs in the hue/saturation/value channel:

- *hue-blobs*: regions of similar color-tone which are surrounded by different (all higher or all lower) color-tones;
- *saturation-blobs*: regions of... yea of what? no idea how to interpret that;
- *value-blobs*: should give very similar results to the grayimage converted RGB image's blobs.

One thing to add: I'm just handling the *detector*! No idea how SIFT/SURF *description* is influenced by color data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but what you could do is using the interest point HSV values as additional matching criteria. What I used in the original implementation and what speeded up matching image pairs was the sign of the determinant of the Hessian matrix. The sign tells us whether it is a light blob on a dark background or a dark blob on a light background. Obviously, one would not attempt to match a dark blob with a bright blob.

In a similar way, you could use HSV values and use the distance. Why matching blue blobs with yellow blobs. Makes no sense, except white balance or lighting is completely messed up. Maybe my [paper about matching line segments](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/en/publications/papers/proceedings/eth_biwi_00344.pdf) can help here. I used HSV there.

As for extracting SURF interest points on the different channels H, S, and V, I agree with the answer of Micka.

What you could try is to make a descriptor using the Hue channel.