# Is there a SURF_CUDA implementation for colored images?

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

Recently started playing around with OpenCV, trying that SURF algorithm, that is really slow on CPU, and does not work with color images on GPU (has an assertion that checks for type==CV_8UC1), and converting images to grayscale gives some pretty bad results.

I'm wondering if there is a colored implementation on gpu in OpenCV, somewhere else, or if there is some kinda tricky workaround like doing the algorithm on all 3 channels and then magically merging them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special handling of color images in OpenCV's non-GPU version of SURF; the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp) shows that it just calls `cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` if it gets an image with more than one channel.

You might try [converting the image to HSV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) and using one or more of the H, S, and/or V channels. More discussion at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804591/color-surf-detector).